# could not find driver when trying to use php_pdo_informix.dll

Tags: php, pdo, driver, informix

I'm trying to use the informix pdo driver but I always get the following error:
"could not find driver"

I'm using the Microsoft IIS with PHPManager and PHP version 5.3.5. The php_pdo_informix.dll is located in the correct folder and enabled in the php.ini

Are there any ideas where the problem lies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use PHP nor pdo drivers, but you can use Process Monitor by SysInternals/Microsoft to see if `php_pdo_informix.dll` is loaded.

Often Informix drivers do not load, because some environment variables are not set. Especially `INFORMIX_DIR`, `CLIENT_LOCALE`, `DB_LOCALE`, `SERVER_LOCALE`, `DBLANG`. Do you have Informix Client installed? Are you able to set up and test ODBC connection?

You can also add directory with `php_pdo_informix.dll` to PATH.

EDIT:

I downloaded `php_pdo_informix.dll` and it seems that this file is broken. I tested it with my Python utility to check dll libraries: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576522-searching-dll-and-exe-files-in-path/

```
c:\download>which_dll.py php_pdo_informix.dll
2011-03-04 08:03:45        32833 [b]    c:\download\php_pdo_informix.dll
ver:5.2.5.5
    trying to load "php_pdo_informix.dll" ...
    Cannot load "php_pdo_informix.dll" !!!
```

And MessageBox appeared (translation from Polish)

```
---------------------------
python.exe - Bad image file
---------------------------
Aplication or libarary DLL c:\download\php_pdo_informix.dll is not correct image of Windowns NT. Check it with install disc.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

SHA1 sum of library I downloaded:

```
b38bc54839c7c4b82e2057763ef1c6584dcbbb1f *php_pdo_informix.dll
```

Comment: php_pdo_informix.dll isn't loaded. The php errors.log: [02-Mar-2011 09:18:19] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library "C:\Program Files\PHP\v5.3\ext\php_pdo_informix.dll"'  Informix client is installed. Adding the php/ext directory to PATH doesn't help either. Still getting the error :(

Comment: What about ODBC connection? They often fail when environment is not propely set, but they give useful information like "unable to load locale categories" or similar. Try it first.

Comment: An ODBC connection could established without any troubles.

Comment: Thank you very much. It really was a broken dll :(

Answer (score 1):

If your PHP is VC9, try this:
[php_pdo_informix_PHP5.3_VC9.zip](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/69579737/php_pdo_informix_PHP5.3_VC9.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and I solved by installing the CSDK from IBM to get the php_pdo_informix.dll to work, you can download it from http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/search.jsp?rs=ifxdl